# uber eats OAuth 2.0 authorization getting error.invalid_request

Tags: uber-api

I tried to integrate pos with uber eats. I followed  https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/user-access-token but getting error response as ***error.invalid_request*** . I entered UBER_CLIENTID, UBER_CLIENTSECRET
correctly and for 1 time it worked and show the login page but later on it showing the error ***error.invalid_request*** . I tried 3 different  browsers and received same error.

[this is the response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ3x5.png)